# How do I grant public access to my file stored in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using the following Curl request :

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=**************************
```

It is giving me error as below :

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to g_stt/abc.flac
```

Comment: Do you need to give access using a program or is it some few files that can be manually access using browser. If it is just some few files. Find the file in the browser, click the options menu for that file. Change permission. Set the new value as “user” and data values “ allUsers” clicking back now you will see your file with a public link.

Comment: You need to use an OAuth 2.0 Access Token and not an API Key. https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 procedures at [Making individual objects publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects), depending on the method you choose. For example using the GCP Console:

> 1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
> 2. In the list of buckets, click on the name of the bucket that you want to make public.
> 3. Select the **Permissions** tab near the top of the page.
> 4. Click the **Add members** button.
> 5. In the **New members** field, enter `allUsers`.
> 6. In the **Roles** drop down, select the **Storage** sub-menu, and click the **Storage Object Viewer** option.
> 7. Click Save.
>
> Once shared publicly, a link icon appears for each object in the
>   *public* access column. You can click on this icon to get the URL for the object.

Or, if you want to make the entire bucket public, follow [Making groups of objects publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the Cloud Console.

https://cloud.google.com/console/storage/browser/

Click on the bucket that hosts your file.  Once inside the bucket you'll see options for modifying the ACL.

As an aside here are instructions for downloading files using curl: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects